# Определение ближайших точек к одной координате (двухмерной)

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется сетка 10 на 10, а также рандомная точка, которая может быть как в центре созданной сетки, так и в углу или у её "стенки"

Как можно определить ближайшие к этой рандомной координате [i, j] точки, которые её окружают? К примеру, имеется точка [5, 6]. Ближайшие точки, которые её окружают (к ней примыкают), будут ([4, 5], [5, 5], [6, 5], [4, 6], [6, 6], [4, 7], [5, 7], [6, 7]). Если точка в углу - [10, 1], то окружающие её будут ([10, 2], [9, 1], [9, 2]), если у стенки - [5, 10], то ([4, 9], [5, 9], [6, 9], [6, 10], [4, 10])

Предполагаю, что это можно сделать с помощью евклидового расстояние и функции min() c параметром key, но как именно- не могу понять.

Comment: что значит `которые её окружают`? Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: В  общем, для того чтобы ответить на этот вопрос нужно понимать что значит "ближайшие точки". Определить одну ближайшую точку - элементарно. Вопрос в том что вы понимаете под всеми ближайшими точками...

Comment: math.floor и math.ceil скорее всего ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Условие наверняка как-то попроще можно записать, но сходу не придумал:

```
def near_points(x, y, arr):
    return [(a,b) for a,b in arr if abs(a-x) <= 1 and abs(b-y) <= 1 and (x != a or y != b)]

points = [(x,y) for x in range(1,11) for y in range(1,11)]

print(near_points(5, 6, points))
print(near_points(10, 1, points))
print(near_points(5, 10, points))
```

Вывод:

```
[(4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (5, 5), (5, 7), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7)]
[(9, 1), (9, 2), (10, 2)]
[(4, 9), (4, 10), (5, 9), (6, 9), (6, 10)]
```

P.S. Упростить выражение можно так, но будет ли так быстрее и понятнее - не уверен:

```
if 0 < (a-x) ** 2 + (b-y) ** 2 <= 2
```

А с функцией `min` тут не получится, потому что она выдаёт только одно значение. Можно было бы поискать минимальное расстояние через неё, но вы его и так знаете - это 1 по одной из координат (и 1 или 0 по другой).

Comment: Если сетка с одинаковым шагом, то можно последнее условие упростить до `0 < (a - x) ** 2 + (b - y) ** 2.0 <= 2.0 * delta ** 2.0`, где delta — шаг сетки

Comment: @AndyPavlov А, точно, `abs` лишний при возведении в квадрат ))  А вот равно - нельзя, надо строго меньше, иначе расстояние [0,2] или [2,0] попадёт в выборку

Comment: @CrazyElf, а не подскажете, что с математической точки зрения означает выражение if 0 < (a-x) ** 2 + (b-y) ** 2 < 4

Comment: @CrazyElf в моей формуле как раз `<=` правильно. `2**2 = 4`, а мое ограничение `2*1**2 = 2`

Comment: @AndyPavlov А, да, не досчитал я. При delta=1 всё правильно, да. Это я ошибся.

Comment: @Bizzarro Ну как бы получается эта формула даёт нам проверить всё то, что у меня расписано в длинном условии, с помощью одной формулы, используя переменные только по одному разу. Наверное, можно трактовать так, что расстояние между точками больше нуля, но меньше 2-х, под это как-раз попадает квадрат вокруг точки, включая диагональные варианты (там расстояние корень из двух получается - меньше, чем 2).

Comment: Еще такой вариант: return [z for z in arr if 0<abs(complex(*z)-complex(x,y))< 2]

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getSurroundingPoints(p, m, n) {
  const res = [];
  for (let i = Math.max(1, p[0] - 1); i <= Math.min(p[0] + 1, m); i++)
    for (let j = Math.max(1, p[1] - 1); j <= Math.min(p[1] + 1, n); j++)
      if (i != p[0] || j != p[1])
        res.push([i, j])
  return res;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getSurroundingPoints([5,  6], 10, 10)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getSurroundingPoints([10, 1], 10, 10)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getSurroundingPoints([5, 10], 10, 10)));
```